# Tesseract iOS camera low accuracy

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, tesseract

When I use an image taken with the camera on the iPhone and send it to `tesseract` the accuracy is horrible it is all garbage text, but when I choose the same image from the photo library I get great accuracy.

How can I improve `tesseract`s accuracy from a picture take with the camera? Here is what I am doing to the image before sending

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGFloat newWidth = 1200;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newWidth);
    image = [image resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc]initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
    [tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#&*()-_:." forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
    [tesseract setVariableValue:@"`~!%^*[]{}<>?|" forKey:@"tessedit_char_blacklist"];
    [tesseract setImage:image];
    [tesseract recognize];
    NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

If anyone has found some "magical" way to get tesseract to scan with great accuracy I will reward a bounty!

Comment: Have you tried without *resizedImage:interpolationQuality:* ?

Comment: Check out this link by using OpenCV to process the images.
[enter link description here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Answer (score 1):

Main things to consider:

- Tesseract needs to be trained for the font and language being recognized.
  It looks like you are supplying appropriate parameters here - are they the same that you use when you supply a predefined image?
- Tesseract doesn't orientate, or 'clean up' images
  When you pass an image to the library, it should already be cleaned up and in portrait. Is the 
  image in photo reel taken from the camera too, or is it a sample image you've saved there somehow?

One check to make is the resize function:

```
CGFloat newWidth = 1200;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newWidth);
```

The original image will be distorted by this, since you are resizing a non-square image into a square image. This will definitely squash the text and make life difficult for Tesseract. At the very least, you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the captured image.

Answer (score -2):

My code work fine, but it´s more complex

```
- (IBAction)captureTapped:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *fullWord = @"";
    OCRImplementation *ocr = [[OCRImplementation alloc] init];

    for(int j = 0; j < [self.images count]; j++){

        UIImage *imageToTesseract = [self.images objectAtIndex:j];

        //UIImage *imageToTesseract = self.imgfinal.image;

        NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];

        @try {
            sortedKeys = [ocr processImageDetectText:imageToTesseract threadhold:198];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];
        }

        NSString *finalWord = @"";
        if([sortedKeys count] > 0){

            for(int i=0; i<[sortedKeys count]; i++){

                UIImage *image = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i];

                finalWord = [self confidencesOCRTesseract:image];
                if(finalWord.length > 1){
                    finalWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[finalWord characterAtIndex:0]];
                }

                fullWord = [fullWord stringByAppendingString:finalWord];

            }

        }

        fullWord = [fullWord stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        [results addObject:fullWord];

        NSLog(@"-- RESULT -- %@",fullWord);
}

    NSString *resultWord = @"";
    if([results count] > 0){
        resultWord = [self calculateStatics:results];
    }
    //Your text Result
    NSLog(@"%@",resultWord);
}

- (NSString*)calculateStatics:(NSMutableArray*)results{

    NSMutableArray *first = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *second = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *third = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *fourth = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *fifth = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *six = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *seven = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i = 0; i<[results count]; i++){

        NSString *result = [results objectAtIndex:i];

        if(result && ![result isEqualToString:@""]){

            if(result.length >= 1 && [result characterAtIndex:0]){
                [first addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:0]]];
            }else{
                [first addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 2 &&[result characterAtIndex:1]){
                [second addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:1]]];
            }else{
                [second addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 3 &&[result characterAtIndex:2]){
                [third addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:2]]];
            }else{
                [third addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 4 &&[result characterAtIndex:3]){
                [fourth addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:3]]];
            }else{
                [fourth addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 5 &&[result characterAtIndex:4]){
                [fifth addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:4]]];
            }else{
                [fifth addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 6 &&[result characterAtIndex:5]){
                [six addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:5]]];
            }else{
                [six addObject:@" "];
            }

            if(result.length >= 7 &&[result characterAtIndex:6]){
                [seven addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [result characterAtIndex:6]]];

            }else{
                [seven addObject:@" "];
            }

        }else{
            [first addObject:@" "];
            [second addObject:@" "];
            [third addObject:@" "];
            [fourth addObject:@" "];
            [fifth addObject:@" "];
            [six addObject:@" "];
            [seven addObject:@" "];
        }

    }

    NSString *word = @"";

    NSCountedSet *frequencies = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:first];
    if([frequencies count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }

    NSCountedSet *frequencies2 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:second];
    if([frequencies2 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies2 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies2 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies2 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies2 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }


    NSCountedSet *frequencies3 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:third];
    if([frequencies3 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies3 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies3 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies3 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies3 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }


    NSCountedSet *frequencies4 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:fourth];
    if([frequencies4 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies4 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies4 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies4 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies4 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }


    NSCountedSet *frequencies5 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:fifth];
    if([frequencies5 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies5 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies5 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies5 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies5 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }

    NSCountedSet *frequencies6 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:six];
    if([frequencies6 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies6 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies6 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies6 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies6 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }

    NSCountedSet *frequencies7 = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:seven];
    if([frequencies7 count] == 1){
        word = [word stringByAppendingString:[[frequencies7 allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }else{

        NSUInteger count = 0;
        NSString *repeatedWord = @"";

        for(int i=0; i<[frequencies7 count]; i++){

            NSString *possibleWord = [[frequencies7 allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSUInteger wordCount = [frequencies7 countForObject:possibleWord];

            if(count < wordCount){
                count = wordCount;
                repeatedWord = possibleWord;
            }

        }

        word = [word stringByAppendingString:repeatedWord];

    }

    return word;

}
```

OCRImplementation class

OCRImplementation.h

```
#ifndef __TesseractSample__OCRImplementation__
#define __TesseractSample__OCRImplementation__

#endif /* defined(__TesseractSample__OCRImplementation__) */

@interface OCRImplementation : NSObject{

}

- (UIImage*)processImage:(id)sender;

- (NSString*)confidencesOCRTesseract:(UIImage*)picture;

@end
```

OCRImplementation.mm

```
#include "OCRImplementation.h"
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
#import "Tesseract.h"

#import "baseapi.h"
#import "environ.h"
#import "pix.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "OpenCV/opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "OpenCV/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "OpenCV/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

@implementation OCRImplementation

- (NSMutableArray*)processImageDetectText:(id)sender threadhold:(int)threadhold{

    UIImage *img1 = sender;
    cv::Mat src = [img1 CVMat];
    cv::Mat src_gray;
    cv::Mat threshold_output;
    cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    int thresh = 100;
    cv::RNG rng(12345);

    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    blur( src_gray, src_gray, cv::Size(3,3) );

    /// Detect edges using Threshold
    cv::threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
    /// Find contours
    cv::findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

    /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
    cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    cv::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
    cv::vector<cv::Point2f>center( contours.size() );
    cv::vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        approxPolyDP( cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect( cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
        minEnclosingCircle( (cv::Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
    }


    /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
    cv::Mat drawing = cv::Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryImages = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableArray *areaArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    float lastArea = 0.0;

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );

        if(boundRect[i].height > 50){

            double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);

            if((boundRect[i].width < boundRect[i].height) && area > (lastArea / 2)){

                lastArea = area;

                [areaArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",area]];

                rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );

                cv::Rect extendedRect = cv::Rect(boundRect[i].x - 5, boundRect[i].y - 5, boundRect[i].width + 10, boundRect[i].height + 10);

                cv::Mat source = src;
                cv::Mat target(extendedRect.size(), source.type());

                if(0 <= extendedRect.x && 0 <= extendedRect.width && extendedRect.x + extendedRect.width <= source.cols && 0 <= extendedRect.y && 0 <= extendedRect.height && extendedRect.y + extendedRect.height <= source.rows){

                    source(extendedRect).copyTo(target);
                    //converting the original image into grayscale
                    cv::cvtColor(target, target, CV_BGR2GRAY);

                    cv::multiply(target, cv::Scalar(2,2,2), target);
                    cv::add(target, cv::Scalar(2,2,2), target);

                    /// Detect edges using Threshold
                    cv::threshold( target, threshold_output, threadhold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
                    cv::dilate(threshold_output, threshold_output, NULL);

                    UIImage *imgFinal = [OCRImplementation imageWithCVMat:threshold_output];

                    [dictionaryImages setObject:imgFinal forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", area]];

                }else{
                    NSLog(@"Error al leer la imagen. NO ROI");
                }


            }



        }

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *finalImages = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[areaArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL]];

    for( int k = 0; k< contours.size(); k++ )
    {

        if(boundRect[k].height > 50){

            for(int i = 0; i < [sortedKeys count]; i++){

                double area = cv::contourArea(contours[k]);

                if(area == [[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]){
                    [finalImages setObject:[dictionaryImages objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",boundRect[k].x]];
                }

            }

        }

    }


    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *keys = [finalImages allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys2 = [keys sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSortDesc context:NULL];

    for(int i=0; i<[sortedKeys2 count]; i++){
        [array addObject:[finalImages objectForKey:[sortedKeys2 objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }


    return array;

}

+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return image;
}

- (NSString*)confidencesOCRTesseract:(UIImage*)picture{

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* tess;

    uint32_t* _pixels;

    NSString* _dataPath = @"tessdata";
    NSString* _language = @"eng";

    // Useful paths
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = ([documentPaths count] > 0) ? [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *dataPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_dataPath];

    // Copy data in Doc Directory
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *tessdataPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_dataPath];
        if (tessdataPath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:nil];
        }
    }

    setenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", [[documentPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"] UTF8String], 1);

    tess = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    tess->Init([_dataPath UTF8String], [_language UTF8String]);

    tess->SetVariable("save_blob_choices", "T");
    tess->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

    //SET IMAGE
    CGSize size = [picture size];
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;

    _pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    // Clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
    memset(_pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a context with RGBA _pixels
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(_pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    // Paint the bitmap to our context which will fill in the _pixels array
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [picture CGImage]);

    // We're done with the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    tess->SetImage((const unsigned char *) _pixels, width, height, sizeof(uint32_t), width * sizeof(uint32_t));

    //END SET IMAGE

    tess->Recognize(NULL);
    tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = tess->GetIterator();
    tesseract::ChoiceIterator* ci;

    // For every identified symbol (there should be only one...)
    NSString *finalWord = @"";

    if(ri != 0) {
        do {
            const char* symbol = ri->GetUTF8Text(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL);
            if(symbol != 0) {
                float conf = ri->Confidence(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL);

                if(conf > 80.0f){

                    finalWord = [finalWord stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:symbol]];

                }else{

                    const tesseract::ResultIterator itr = *ri;
                    ci = new tesseract::ChoiceIterator(itr);
                    // For every chosen candidate...
                    do {

                        const char* choice = ci->GetUTF8Text();
                        NSString *choiceStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:choice];
                        if(choice && ![choiceStr isEqualToString:@""]){
                            finalWord = [finalWord stringByAppendingString:choiceStr];
                            break;
                        }else{
                            finalWord = [finalWord stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:symbol]];
                        }

                    } while(ci->Next());

                    delete ci;

                }

            }
            delete[] symbol;
        } while((ri->Next(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL)));
    }

    return finalWord;

}

NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context) {
    NSString *n1 = (NSString *) num1;
    NSString *n2 = (NSString *) num2;
    n1 = [[n1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    n2 = [[n2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([n1 floatValue] > [n2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([n1 floatValue] < [n2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

NSInteger intSortDesc(id num1, id num2, void *context) {
    NSString *n1 = (NSString *) num1;
    NSString *n2 = (NSString *) num2;
    n1 = [[n1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    n2 = [[n2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([n1 floatValue] < [n2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([n1 floatValue] > [n2 floatValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}


@end
```